# Using sed to search and replace an ip address in a file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, ip

Been trying to get this working for a while and not really quite getting it.
Basically, I have a file with an ip address that changes more or less on a daily basis. The file only contains one ip address and this is the one I'm trying to replace with my crazy grepping to find my current internal ip.

I have this

```
#!/bin/sh

newip=$(ifconfig | grep 0xfff | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | grep -v 255)

echo $newip
sed 's/*\.*\.*\.*/"$newip"/g' log.txt > logmod.txt
```

but it's not matching and replacing.
I'm not familiar with sed and I am a beginner with regexps too.

Any help would be awesome!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your version of `sed` supports extended regular expressions (the `-r` option), you could do something like this (which is similar to what you have in your `grep` statement). Also note `$newip` is outside the single quotes to allow the shell to replace it.

```
sed -r 's/(\b[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b'/"$newip"/
```

BTW this solution still matches strings that do not represent IP addresses. See [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) under **IP Adresses** for more complex solutions.

Comment: Be advised that the "\b" (word boundary) construct isn't standard.

Comment: @Steve: That's true. I tested the expression with **GNU sed version 4.2.1**. Since the OP added the `bash` tag I assumed he might have some version of **GNU sed** as well. Also note that I specifically mention the `-r` option.

Comment: You, my friend, have saved me so many hours of stress! My version of sed did not unfortunately support -r so I used homebrew (I'm using a Mac) and installed the latest version which worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 's/old ip/new ip/g' filename
```

Comment: Please don't simply post code. Add some context to your answer. Take a look at [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: how do you handle the dot wildcard?

Answer (score 1):

```
IP=207.0.0.2; [[ x${IP}x =~ x"(2([0-4][0-9])|2(5[0-5])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(2([0-4][0-9])|2(5[0-5])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(2([0-4][0-9])|2(5[0-5])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(2([0-4][0-9])|2(5[0-5])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])"x ]] && echo ok || echo bad
```

this validates only four decimal octet representation
so this one will fail 016.067.006.200 
(even valid but not four decimal octet representation, but octal)

```
016.067.006.200 =~ 14.55.6.200
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/ \(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{1,3\}\).[0-9]/NEW_IP/g'
```

Comment: Surely the OP wants the replacement to be the value of a variable, not the static text `NEW_IP`. The single quotes inhibit variable interpolation, and anyway, the existing answers already cover this.