# Replacing IP with current ip recursively

Tags: regex, linux, sed, ip

I have folders with `.env` file in each of them

```
Folder1
  .env
Folder2
  .env
Folder3
  .env
Folder4
  .env
```

.env file have

```
IP_ADDRESS=192.168.1.132
```

I wan to change IP of .env with current Local IP.

```
CurrentIP=`ifconfig | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep -E '(192)\.(168)(\.[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]){2}'`

echo 'Assiged IP' $CurrentIP

find ./ -name '.env' -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3})/$CurrentIP/" {} \;
```

it doesn't seems to working, What's going wrong.

Comment: Can you give a hint on what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sed to search and replace an ip address in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5277156/608639), [Replace all IP addresses in a file to a specified string(https://stackoverflow.com/q/35276822/608639), [Replace IP Address from file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42921277/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex in `sed` is not correct. Please try

```
find ./ -name '.env' -type f -exec sed -i '' -E "s/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/$CurrentIP/" {} \;
```

1. Using extended (modern) regular expressions `-E`
2. Duplicate closed bracket in the regex `[0-9]{1,3})`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-exec` flag of `find` as follows:

```
find . -name '.env' -type f -exec sed -i "pattern" '{}' \;
```